# Rails Logger with shift_age = 'daily' does not rotate when size of the file is small

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails Logger with shift_age = 'daily', looks like it does not rotate the log file when the size is small or if logs do not populate daily.

It works fine in my production environment, but in staging environment it does not rotate, below is my code.

```
FileUtils.touch(Rails.root.join('log/custom_log.json'))
@@custom_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log/custom_log.json'), shift_age = 'daily')
```

Comment: Is there a default minimum size for logrotate, currently my log filr log/custom_log.json size is 5.7K

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```rb
FileUtils.touch(Rails.root.join('log', 'custom_log.json'))
@@custom_logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 
'custom_log.json'), 'daily')
```

This example [from the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-How+to+create+a+logger) might also work:

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join('log', 'custom_log.json'), File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
logger = Logger.new(file)
```

Also note that most log examples seem to create files with the `.log` file format.